# Making sublists a part of a larger list

Tags: python, pandas

I have appended many lists to a larger list but the problem is now I have many sublists within the list which is problematic. This is a shortened version of the list that only includes the Price list:

[image: largerlist]

As you can see, each element in the list has a list within it. Ideally I would like to make each element in the nested lists into a different element in the list. It should look a little like this (ignore the rounding, that's just excel):

[image: broken up list]

The way I currently get the data is by converting a section of a dataframe to list and appending it to this list. The code for that looks a little bit like this:

```
### shortened version

# goes through each part of the dataframe
for n in range(len(list_of_dfs)):
    # grabs the price list for that specific dataframe and converts it to a list and appends.
    price.append(list_of_dfs[n]['Price'].tolist())

# create dataframe
columns = ['Current Time', 'Price', 'Moving Average', 'Action']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# add list values to column
data['Price'] = price

data.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: What if you just used `extend` instead of `append`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Samwise for providing the answer. It was as simple as changing the .append for the dataframe lists to .extend.

```
### shortened version

# goes through each part of the dataframe
for n in range(len(list_of_dfs)):
    # grabs the price list for that specific dataframe and converts it to a list and extend.
    price.extend(list_of_dfs[n]['Price'].tolist())

# create dataframe
columns = ['Current Time', 'Price', 'Moving Average', 'Action']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# add list values to column
data['Price'] = price

data.to_csv('test.csv')
```